# how to pass any object using openDDS?

Tags: idl, data-distribution-service, opensplice

I'm using openDDS pub/sun middleware. I have tested openDDS using complex structure.

e.g .

```
typedef struct DSMD
    {
          string a;           
          long b;

    } StandByModeData;

   struct DSMCD{        
    string SessionId;       
    DSMD Data;
  };
```

but now I have different structure.which is pass over the openDDS.

how can I use template in idl structure?

I need something like this.

```
template <struct T> 
struct array { 
  T typr;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that is currently not possible with OpenDDS. IDL3+ does define templated modules which is like your example, but that is not supported with OpenDDS or any other DDS vendor as far as I know.

Comment: Can I pass atleast wrapped object? So that I can pass any type of object

Comment: I need to pass any type of object. How can define idl for that?

Answer (score 0):

Fast-RTPS from eProsima could support large variety of data types using DDS, aka the dynamic type builder, some sample dynamic builder could refer to [here](https://github.com/eProsima/Fast-RTPS/tree/master/examples/C%2B%2B/DynamicHelloWorldExample) and the github repo refer to https://github.com/eProsima/Fast-RTPS . IMHO, when the data type support std::string type, it could be support any kind of data type, since std::string is a versatile choice. For uncertain data type, you could cast the data into a json formatted string to pass through the DDS. I've been working on such thing, further progress would be forwarded here later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do your own VMF (variable message format) message type. Code I'm working on now uses this concept to pass messages between nodes/participants using eprosima FastDDS. The same idl file can be used for OpenDDS and FastDDS. We use both DDS implementations concurrently in some instances.

```
@topic
struct VariableMessageType
{
   /* Message id */
   long msg_id; 

   /* Number of bytes in the data vector */
   /* units: none */
   long num_bytes; 

   /* num_bytes sized array of bytes */
   /* units: none */
   sequence<octet> data; 
};
```